# How to put value into span cell using aspose.cell?

Tags: c#, .net, aspose-cells

I am using Aspose. Cell for .net to write some data into Excel. I have a quick question:

what are the best practices to get and write a value into the below cell?

[image]

this kind of cell may be across multiple columns/rows,  does it belong to [Rang](https://apireference.aspose.com/cells/net/aspose.cells/range) or a special [cell](https://apireference.aspose.com/cells/net/aspose.cells/cell)?

[image]

thanks

Answer (score 2):

If it is merged cell, then you should use Cell object (you may use its PutValue method  to insert data). Please note, in MS Excel sheet, when you merge a range of cells, the merged cell’s name will be top left cell,
so it will be accessed by that name. For example, when you merge "B1:F3" cells, it will become one big cell (B1). Now you got to access and insert data into B1 cell if you want to insert some data into that merged area range.

PS. I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: oh.  one more a question:  what's the Rang? how it looks like

Comment: A Range in an Excel spreadsheet is a collection of some (selected) cell(s). The range is usually symmetrical (square), but  it can also be based on separate cells (non contiguous). The range can be referred to in a formula as well. For complete reference, see the document (https://www.excel-easy.com/introduction/range.html) for your needs.